# How do I manipulate functions to take new arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering how I could manipulate a function to take a new argument in Python without modifying original formula.

For example, how would I take square function and make another function like multiply square using square function as a model:

Original Function:

```py
def square(x):
 result = (x*x)
 return(result)
```

New Function, takes a new argument "y":

```py
def multSquare(x,y):
 result = y*square(x)
 return(result)
```

I tried using decorators but I can't seem to have it working

```py
def addArg(tarFun):
 def wrapArg(y, *args, **kwargs):
  result=tarFun(*args, **kwargs) * y
  return result
 return wrapArg

def square(x):
 result = (x*x)
 return(result)

multSquare = addArg(square)

print(square(2)) # This should be 4
print(multSquare(2,3)) # This should be 12
```

This doesn't work because I don't how to inject y.

In the end, I want to make a function that takes all the arguments of the original function plus one more argument.

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pay attention to the order of your arguments, what's happening is that you are squaring 3 and multiplying it by 2. This is because your function `wrapArg` uses the first argument (`2`) as the number you are multiplying with and the second (`3`) as the number you are squaring.

`multSquare(3, 2)` will give the result you want.

Comment: Thanks this works for me! Can you change the placement of the new argument in the function to have it in the last argument or somewhere in between or does it always have to be up front? Can I use "def wrapArg(*args, y, **kwargs):"?

Comment: You could do something like that, but you will always have to use the keyword `y` to define its value. It won't be a positional argument anymore. In your example, it would be `multSquare(2, y=3)`.

Answer (score 0):

In additional to what busybear said you could just swap the parameters around

```py
def addArg(fun):
    def wrapArg(x, y):
        result = fun(x) * y
        return result
    return wrapArg


def square(x):
    result = (x * x)
    return(result)


multSquare = addArg(square)

print(square(2))  # This should be 4
print(multSquare(2, 3))  # This should be 12
```

or additionally just use optional arguments

```py
def square(x, y = None):
    sq = x*x
    if y:
        sq *= y
    return sq
```

Comment: Thank you Jordan, I was hoping to not modify my original function so I can't really use the optional arguments as you suggest and because I want to write a generic  wrapper that works for all function, I can't really define the argument. I would have to stick with *args, **kwargs. Because of your comment, it makes me wonder if it is possible to define a placement for the new argument, instead of always being the first argument.

Comment: I do think if you looked more into decorators it would work! I don't understand them too well but it seems possible. You can make the *args, the first argument but you would just have to refer to the second argument by name when calling the function, otherwise args would envelope it.